# While Controller is not looping all the values in the array from Regex( -1 ) results

Tags: while-loop, jmeter, counter, performance-testing

Im having the requirement like i need to loop through all the values that are capturing from regex with match No -1

```
ThreadGroup
 ---Req1
 ---Req2
 ---RegEx: with Match No. -1 (Debug Sampler shows match count : **18** )
 ---JSR223 Sampler ( Setting the counter value to 1 --**vars.put("counter1","1");**)
 ---While Controller ( **${__javaScript(parseInt(vars.get("counter1"))<=(${Task_matchNr}),)}** )
      ----Http req inside While controller 
      ----JSR223 Sampler(Increasing the counter value by 1 everytime till Task_matchNr --**counter = counter+1; vars.put("counter1",Integer.toString(counter));**
```

Everytime it will execute till 11th value correctly and again it start executing from 1st value without exiting the loop

Could someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need the counter as While Controller exposes current iteration via `${__jm__While Controller__idx}` (since [JMeter 5.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/what-is-new-jmeter-5/))
2. You're comparing integer to a string, you should do something like `parseInt("${Task_matchNr}")` `
3. It's better to use more performing function than JavaScript, for example [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3), the relevant syntax would be something like:

   ```
   ${__jexl3("${Task_matchNr}" != "${__jm__While Controller__idx}",)}
   ```
4. Wouldn't be easier to use [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) instead?

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri, as suggested i have changed my while controller to ForEach now, but whats happening is i have Taskid and dbid (both will get same match count)  to iterate through ForEach Contoller, i have placed Taskid in ForEach and dbid in counter inside - issue is some requests are failing ( only 0.6% failed out of 500 requests) because of dbid and taskid mismatch

Could you please help

Comment: can you please help?